# atteita vs atteimashita

Tags: past

I am learning Japanese and I'm always mixing these two. Can someone explain what's the difference between them and how are they used?

My only understanding is the first is `verb+tte+ita` which is kinda like "it was like that" but the other one I have no idea and it's used in all the same cases.

Answer (score 1):

atteita(あっていた) and atteimashita(あっていました) both mean the same, and they mean "it was right". The difference between them are politeness. atteita is a casual expression and atteimashita is a formal one. So if you talk to your friends you can say atteita, and if you want to talk to your teacher or your boss, you can say atteimashita.